# Way to find which process is spawining another process in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I noticed in one of my development servers that there is test-script that executes a command that hogs the CPU for 10 seconds every 10 seconds.

I killed the process running the test-script but upon monitoring running processes, I noticed the test-script is periodically kicked off by some unknown process. I'm thinking its some cron job kicking this off. Is there a way to find out which process is executing this test-script periodically?

Comment: `ps faux` will show parents.

Comment: ... and cron starts should be in some log, syslog, other dedicated log, depends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a process ID and it's parent's ID using `ps`:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid 4708
  PID  PPID
 4708  4580
```

Or you can just get it's parent's ID:

```
$ ps -o ppid= 4708
 4580
```